# Writing pytest testcases for asyncio with streams

Tags: python-asyncio, stdout, pytest-asyncio, nest-asyncio

I am trying to write a pytest testcase for a asyncio function which does read the output streams (stderr/stdout) and modifies the lines. The function I want to test (which again gets called inside `asyncio.gather`) is as shown below:

```
import asyncio

async def watch(stream):

    while True:
        lines = await stream.read(2**16)
        if not lines or lines == "":
            break

        lines = lines.strip().split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            print(f'myPrefix-{line}')
```

The pytest testcase I wrote is as follows:

```
import asyncio
from io import StringIO
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_watch(event_loop):
    expected_outcome = "myPrefix-This is stdout"

    def write_something():
        print("This is stdout")

    with patch("sys.stdout", new=StringIO()) as mock_stdout:
        write_something()
        output = await watch(mock_stdout.getvalue())
        assert output.return_value == expected_outcome
```

However, when I execute this pytest I encounter `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'` . How to test asyncio coroutines while dealing with stdout/stderr streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringIO` does not have coroutine methods for `read`, so you can't mock this and have it work with your watch coroutine function (calling `getvalue` on the `StringIO` instance also just passes in the string written to stdout, which explains the error you get). Assuming that the stream in your watch function is an instance of `StreamReader`, you can just create an asyncio `StreamReader` instance in your test and use the `feed_data` method to write something to the stream. Then you can pass this in to `watch`. You can then use the `capsys` fixture included with Pytest to capture what `watch` writes to stdout.

Below is an updated version of your code that passes as a standalone:

```
import asyncio
import pytest


async def watch(stream):
    while True:
        lines = await stream.read(2 ** 16)
        if not lines or lines == "":
            break

        lines = lines.decode().strip().split("\n") #note the use of decode()
        for line in lines:
            print(f'myPrefix-{line}')


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_watch(capsys):
    expected_outcome = "myPrefix-This is stdout\n"

    stream = asyncio.StreamReader()
    stream.feed_data(b'This is stdout\n')
    stream.feed_eof()

    await watch(stream)
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == expected_outcome
```